# Eclipse plugin view is empty when installed

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing an eclipse plugin with a view. When launched in dev mode it's displaying and working perfectly fine:
[image: Launched from Eclipse run configuration]
But when I packaged and installed the plugin in the Eclipse instance, the view is empty when launched:
[image: Installed in an Eclipse instance]
EDIT:
Looking at Error Log view, sometimes there is the following error:

```
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: swing2swt/layout/BorderLayout
```

It might be relevant because a swing2swt.jar was magically automatically added to my plugin project by Eclipse. I tried including it in the build but the build failed complaining there is no value set for source.swing2swt.jar which I totally don't understand why it needs setting.

Comment: Are you developing and deploying to the same version? is that the **entirety** of what was reported?

Comment: I wanted to use Neon to develop plugins for Luna compatibility. I didn't know how to create target definitions when I first encountered the problem. But the problem persisted after I switched to Luna for development. The plugin shows when run in dev mode in Luna, but is blank when installed. Now I'm trying target definition and it's still the same for me. By the way, error log is no longer showing missing dependencies error. I'll update the question relfecting this.

Comment: Try adding some tracing: https://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_use_the_platform_debug_tracing_facility

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to this problem.

The problem itself is caused by swing2swt.jar not included in the build. For some reason WindowBuilder automatically added this jar to the project but didn't mark it for inclusion in the build.

However the struggle here is because Eclipse doesn't delete plugin jar files when uninstalling "software" that was previously installed. So if the version does not advance, the cached old, wrong plugin jar file will be reused when reinstalling the feature, causing any non-version-advancing fixes uneffective when reinstalling the feature/plugin.

It is so very common that during the development of a plugin, version does not advance for small fixes when trying distribution so I think this needs to be fixed. A ticket has been created at Eclipse site.
[Bug 509781](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=509781)